# Macro to Filter Data table on multiple criteria based on specific cell value

Tags: vba, excel, filtering

I tried to record a macro to filter a data table based on the values of 2 cells. It only worked the first time because VBA recorded the cell value instead of the cell reference. I have not been able to figure out how to alter the code to do the following:

1. Change the filter selection when the cell value changes
2. have the filter selection change without navigating to the worksheet containing the data table.

The worksheet where the reference cells are located is called "Cost Estimator" and the worksheet with the data table is "AR_BOM"

The table name is "BOM_Table"

Here is the code that was recorded:

```
Sub Filter_AR_BOM()
'
' Filter_AR_BOM Macro
'

'
    Range("E25").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("AR_BOM").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("BOM_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
        "Line 11"
    Sheets("Cost Estimator").Select
    Range("J10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("AR_BOM").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("BOM_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1 _
        :="12197118"
    Sheets("Cost Estimator").Select
End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been trying different things from forums for almost 2 days and don't seem to be making any headway. I'm an extreme macro/vba novice, so I know that doesn't help anything.

Comment: So when either of two cells is changed you want to rerun the filter? Which two cells? E25 and J10?

Comment: yes, when either of the 2 cells (e25 & J10) are changed, it will update the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start at least. The code needs to go in the Cost Estimator sheet module

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$E$25" Or Target.Address = "$J$10" Then
    Sheets("AR_BOM").ListObjects("BOM_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Range("E25").value
    Sheets("AR_BOM").ListObjects("BOM_Table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Range("J10").value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, so I pasted that code into the cost estimate worksheet module, but it's still not working. I opened up the "Macro" list from the developer toolbar and ran the Macro, and it still din't work.

Comment: That code won't appear in the macro list. It is run when you change one of those cells.